# Pipeline job parameters not passed from pipeline yaml

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines

I'm running a pipeline job with a sweep step in AzureML.
I'm using the CLI syntax to create the components.  I have a `pipeline.yaml` file that refers to `train.yaml` as the trial.  `train.yaml` in turn calls `train.py`.

The job fails after launch because the path that I'm passing it as an argument within `train.py`, which should be `azureml:dataset_name:1`, is None.

To test what is going on, I logged the other arguments passed.  And I discovered that even though I specify the parameters you see below:
[image]

in my logger, the values are those that coincide with the defaults in my `add_argument` definition within `train.py` (the below is from the log of one of the child runs in the sweep):
[image]

So let's ignore the question of the path being None for now.  I want to understand why the values from `pipeline.yaml` aren't being passed correctly.  I triple-checked my arguments and the names match between the 3 files.

For reference:

`pipeline.yaml`

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelineJob.schema.json
type: pipeline
display_name: test_sweep
description: Tune hyperparameters
settings:
  default_compute: azureml:test-compute
jobs:
  sweep_step:
    type: sweep
    inputs:
      data_path:
        type: uri_file
        path: azureml:test_data:1
      seq_length: 100
      epochs: 1
    outputs:
      model_output:
    sampling_algorithm: random
    search_space:
      batch_size:
        type: choice
        values: [1, 5, 10, 15]
      learning_rate:
        type: loguniform
        min_value: -6.90775527898
        max_value: -2.30258509299
    trial: ./train.yaml
    objective:
      goal: maximize
      primary_metric: bleu_score
    limits:
      max_total_trials: 5
      max_concurrent_trials: 3
      timeout: 3600 # 1 hour
      trial_timeout: 720 # 20 mins
```

`train.yaml`

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandComponent.schema.json
type: command

name: train_model
display_name: train_model
version: 1

inputs:
  data_path:
    type: uri_file
  batch_size:
    type: integer
  learning_rate:
    type: number
  seq_length:
    type: integer
  epochs:
    type: integer

outputs:
  model_output:
    type: mlflow_model

code: ../src

environment: azureml:test_env:2

command: >-
  python train.py
    --data_path ${{inputs.data_path}}
    --output_path ${{outputs.model_output}}
    --batch_size ${{inputs.batch_size}}
    --learning_rate ${{inputs.learning_rate}}
    --seq_length ${{inputs.seq_length}}
    --epochs ${{inputs.epochs}}
```

`train.py` (just the relevant part)

```py
import argparse
import logging

def main(args):
    data_path = args.data_path
    output_path = args.output_path
    batch_size = args.batch_size
    seq_length = args.seq_length
    epochs = args.epochs
    learning_rate = args.learning_rate

    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger.info(f'path: {data_path}')
    logger.info(f'batch_size: {batch_size}')
    logger.info(f'seq_length: {seq_length}')
    logger.info(f'epochs: {epochs}')

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--data_path", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--output_path")
    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=5)
    parser.add_argument("--learning_rate", type=float, default=1e-5)
    parser.add_argument("--seq_length", type=int, default=500)
    parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=3)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    main(args)
```